# Centos 6 x2go dependancy issues when trying to run yum update

Tags: linux, centos, x11, x11forwarding

I have tried to update **x2goserver** to the latest version on my CentOS server however I am getting a dependency issues now.

From what I can tell it is looking for ***xorg-x11-fonts-core*** package. This appears to not be part of CentOS 6 and only OpenSuse. Has anyone else had this issue? Do you think it is a bug with the latest RPM's or is there anything I can do to resolve the issue? x2go does not have a forum so I thought I would post here

```
[root@fileserver$ ~]# yum install x2goserver
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.as29550.net
 * epel: nl.mirror.eurid.eu
 * extras: mirrors.manchester.icecolo.com
 * updates: mirror.as29550.net
X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go                                                                                                                | 1.3 kB     00:00
Not using downloaded repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:
  Current   : Tue Feb 26 11:43:35 2013
  Downloaded: Thu Feb 21 18:44:54 2013
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package x2goserver.x86_64 0:4.0.0.0-4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: x2goagent for package: x2goserver-4.0.0.0-4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package x2goagent.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nxagent for package: x2goagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nxagent.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xext.so.6 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xrandr.so.2 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xrender.so.1 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xcomposite.so.1 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xdmcp.so.6 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXcompext.so.3 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_X11.so.6 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0) for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xinerama.so.1 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xpm.so.4 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXcompshad.so.3 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xfixes.so.3 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomp.so.3 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_freetype.so.6 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30) for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xtst.so.6 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-core for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libNX_Xdamage.so.1 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libNX_X11-6.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_X11-6.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomp.so.3 for package: libNX_X11-6-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
---> Package libNX_Xcomposite1.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xcomposite1.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xdamage1.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xdamage1.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xdmcp6.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xdmcp6.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xext6.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xext6.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xfixes3.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xfixes3.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xinerama1.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xinerama1.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xpm4.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xpm4.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xrandr2.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xrandr2.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xrender1.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xrender1.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_Xtst6.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_Xtst6.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libNX_freetype6.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be updated
---> Package libNX_freetype6.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be an update
---> Package libxml2.i686 0:2.7.6-8.el6_3.4 will be installed
---> Package nxagent.i686 0:3.5.0.17-4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXcompext.so.3 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXcompshad.so.3 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomp.so.3 for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-core for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686
---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.3-27.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686 (X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go)
           Requires: libXcompshad.so.3
Error: Package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686 (X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go)
           Requires: libXcomp.so.3
Error: Package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686 (X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go)
           Requires: libXcompext.so.3
Error: Package: libNX_X11-6-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686 (X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go)
           Requires: libXcomp.so.3
Error: Package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686 (X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go)
           Requires: xorg-x11-fonts-core
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news! Dependency issue has now been resolved by the developer who looks after the repo

simply run.

```
yum install x2goserver
```

All sorted

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your locally cached copy of the repository metadata:

```
X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go                                                                                                                | 1.3 kB     00:00
Not using downloaded repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:
  Current   : Tue Feb 26 11:43:35 2013
  Downloaded: Thu Feb 21 18:44:54 2013
```

When I went to [inspect the original](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/RemoteDesktop:/x2go/RHEL_6/repodata/), I found it indeed did have a date of Feb 21. Where you got the cached file you have, I could not begin to say.

To resolve the issue, clear your yum cache.

```
yum clean all
```

Comment: Tried this still didn't work. however the message 'Not using downloaded repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:' has gone now

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it fails. I forced install but after that it did not work.
I also tried to rebuild the SRPM but somehow it still has that dependancy.
I see they fixed SLES 11 so hopefully RHEL 6 will follow soon.
Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

While he may need to update his yum cache, it has nothing to do with his error: 
Error: Package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-4.1.i686 (X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go)
           Requires: xorg-x11-fonts-core

I am seeing the same thing on my Scientific Linux 6 systems:

```
yum install x2goserver 
Loaded plugins: etckeeper, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security, versionlock
145 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package x2goserver.x86_64 0:4.0.0.0-4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: x2goagent for package: x2goserver-4.0.0.0-4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package x2goagent.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nxagent for package: x2goagent-3.5.0.17-3.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nxagent.x86_64 0:3.5.0.17-3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-core for package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-3.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nxagent-3.5.0.17-3.1.x86_64 (X11_RemoteDesktop_x2go)
           Requires: xorg-x11-fonts-core
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

They have added a requirement for xorg-x11-fonts-core package to the RedHat rpms, yet that package is an OpenSuse package that doesn't not exist in RedHat 6 or it's derivatives.

Comment: Yes I think this is the exact problem. I im guessing there isn't much I can do until the developers fix this dependency issue for Red Hat 6. Hopefully they realise this quickly. Is there anything I can do in the mean time?

Comment: X2go team are now aware of the issue. Hopfully they will update the rpm repo soon

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.terminal-server.x2go.devel/4824

Answer (score 0):

that's right. Package xorg-x11-fonts-core does not exist on RHEL , CentOS SL.
I tried to create a bug report, which is done by a mailing list (argh!).
You could try to the same, more info here:
http://bugs.x2go.org/

Please do so and follow the instructions, it will probably be fixed soon after.

I did this to work around the problem:
yum install libXcomp3 libXcompext3 libXcompshad3 nxagent --skip-broken
and then yum update .
It only shows nxagent as not updateable then.
You might force it, but I did not do that.

Comment: Tried this however even with  --skip-broken it doesn't work. there has been an update to nxagent for all but RHEL 6 x64 version. I have highlighted this. Looks like they have seen the issue after i hightlighted it http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.terminal-server.x2go.devel/4929. Hopefully a fix for x64 soon